# Can not pass values inside a struct, when use the struct pointer as an argument to a thread function correctly?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a very simply code to use C++11 thread. I found that if I use struct pointer as an argument for the threaded function, the value inside the struct can not be passed correctly.
Please tell me where I did wrong. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int tid;
    int bbb;
} arguments;


void blahblah (void * args) {
    int tid1 = ((arguments*)args)->tid;
    int b = ((arguments*)args)->bbb;

    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", tid1, b);
}


int main ()  {
    int n = 5;
    // thread * ThreadArray = (thread*)malloc(n * sizeof(thread));
    thread  ThreadArray[n]; 

    int tid = 0, bbb = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arguments args = {tid, bbb};
        tid++;
        bbb--;
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", args.tid, args.bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread (blahblah, &args);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ThreadArray[i].join ();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The result is like:

```
the data inside 0, 6 
the data inside 1, 5 
the data inside 2, 4  
the data inside 3, 3 
the tid is 3, 3   
the tid is 3, 3
the tid is 4, 2
the data inside 4, 2   
the tid is 4, 2   
the tid is 4, 2
```

Comment: You aren't passing a struct as an argument, you're passing a pointer as an argument.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to pass the pointer, which points to the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your loop, you are passing a pointer to a local `arguments` variable that goes out of scope right after the `std::thread` constructor exits, so the memory is likely to be invalid by the time `blahblah()` tries to access it.

You would have to declare the `arguments` memory outside of the loop so it stays around long enough for `blahblah()` to use it, eg:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct arguments {
    int tid;
    int bbb;
};

void blahblah (arguments * args) {
    int tid1 = args->tid;
    int b = args->bbb;

    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", tid1, b);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 5;

    thread ThreadArray[n]; 
    arguments args[n];

    int tid = 0, bbb = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        args[i].tid = tid++;
        args[i].bbb = bbb--;
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", args[i].tid, args[i].bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread(blahblah, &args[i]);
    }

    for (auto &t : ThreadArray) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct arguments {
    int tid;
    int bbb;
};

void blahblah (unique_ptr<arguments> &args) {
    int tid1 = args->tid;
    int b = args->bbb;

    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", tid1, b);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 5;

    thread ThreadArray[n]; 

    int tid = 0, bbb = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        auto args = make_unique<arguments>();
        args->tid = tid++;
        args->bbb = bbb--;
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", args->tid, args->bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread(blahblah, move(args));
    }

    for (auto &t : ThreadArray) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Or, you can pass the `arguments` *by value* instead:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct arguments {
    int tid;
    int bbb;
};

void blahblah (arguments args) {
    int tid1 = args.tid;
    int b = args.bbb;

    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", tid1, b);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 5;

    thread ThreadArray[n]; 

    int tid = 0, bbb = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arguments args{tid++, bbb--};
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", args.tid, args.bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread(blahblah, args);
    }

    for (auto &t : ThreadArray) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Or, you caan simply get rid of `arguments` altogether, as `std::thread` supports functions with multiple parameters:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void blahblah (int tid, int bbb) {
    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", tid, bbb);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 5;

    thread ThreadArray[n]; 

    int tid = 0, bbb = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", tid, bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread(blahblah, tid++, bbb--);
    }

    for (auto &t : ThreadArray) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the address of a temporary `arguments` instance, so you have no guarantees it's valid when your thread tries to use it.  Instead, pass the `args` directly, since C++'s thread library supports arguments by value.

```
void blahblah (arguments args)
{
    printf("the tid is %d, %d\n", args.tid, args.bbb);
}

// ...

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arguments args = {tid, bbb};
        tid++;
        bbb--;
        printf("the data inside %d, %d\n", args.tid, args.bbb);
        ThreadArray[i] = thread (blahblah, args);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. If I do need to pass a struct pointer under some cases, what 
 do I do? Because the struct need to hold output message sometimes for the threaded function.

Comment: You need to ensure the point remains valid for as long as needed.  Ideally, you'd use a smart pointer (unique_ptr or shared_ptr) since they handle lifetime for you.

Comment: @YueWang You can use a `std::shared_ptr` for such case.

Comment: @YueWang instance of `arguments` created by statement `arguments args = {tid, bbb};` stops existing after execution reaches the least nested enclosing brace }. New one may or may not be created in same spot on next iteration. You have to ensure that life of object is no less than life of thread while it uses that object